# Validate and sort a variety of serial numbers with different formats?

Tags: c#

I am faced with the following issue.  I need to capture a range of serial numbers in c# to be stored in a database.  If these serial numbers are just numbers, it is fine, but I have ran into serial numbers which are alpha-numeric such as:

56AAA71064D6 and 56AAA7105A25

How can I accommodate the different possibilities that serial number ranges may be in?

Assuming that all serial numbers have some order, how can I parse the sequential part of it?

The database takes the serial numbers as strings already.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? It your question about how to store the values ? You will need to store them as a string.

Comment: `string serialNumber` in C# or `SerialNumber VARCHAR(something)` in sql?

Comment: You want to enforce the format of the serial in the database schema?

Comment: My guess is that these are hexadecimal numbers.  So one option would be to parse these hexadecimel strings and store the number.  (This is just a guess based upon a sample set of two so could well be wrong.)

Comment: You are right, it is hexadecimal, but this is just one example.  Other serial numbers may just be numbers or alphanumeric serials that do not contain hex.

Comment: @driis, wow I wonder being so clear you still need explanation on what exactly is question?

Comment: If they are already strings in the DB, then is the question about validation of the serial numbers, or sorting, or what?

Comment: @jball - Both, validation becomes more cumbersome if the serial numbers can have varying formats and sorting them.

Comment: @Akash Kava, how have you determined what the OP means? Do they need a starting and ending value for the current serial numbers, or do they need to capture a variety of serial numbers? The followup comments sure sound like the latter.

Comment: @Xaisoft, perhaps the question should be titled "Validate and sort a variety of serial numbers with different formats?"

Comment: Personally, I still don't understand your problem.  Sorting serial numbers represented by a key generally just means calling a built in sort function, though maybe you'd need to pass a Comparison delegate or whatever if you need special rules.  Checking if a key is valid has no real meaning, unless you start out with a format and wish to verify the key fits it, or just want to check if it is in the database.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your serial numbers have same width then its easy...

you have to use string.compare method to get the range.

```
int MaxLength = 20;

private string Pad(string val){
   if(val.Length < 20){
      val = new String('0', MaxLength - val.Length) + val;
   }
   return val;
}

public bool IsBetween(string num, string start, string end){
    num = Pad(num);
    start = Pad(num);
    end = Pad(num);
    return String.Compare(num,start)>=0 && String.Compare(num,end)<=0;
}
```

And if you sort all serial numbers, then you can easily pickup range.

If they are not of same width then you have to padd 0 before smaller length strings to make them all same size.

Comment: The problem is that the serial numbers could vary in width and vary in format.

Comment: I have added padding code, which can pad the smaller numbers with leading zeros, that will make them all same width. You can replace '0' with empty space if you wish. And you can change case to upper case if you want case insensitve comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If your database assumes the serial number is numeric, you either need to change that part of the DB to allow alphanumeric values, or else define a new mapping table to correlate the external serial number with a unique numeric ID so that you can continue to use numbers for the database's internal representation of a serial 'number'.

You'd also have to add support to hand out a new, unique internal serial number for a given alphanumeric input in a concurrency-safe way.

EDIT: What I mean by this is that when a new alphanumeric serial number has to be registered in the DB, you should do this with a transaction that atomically adds a record to the original (numeric) serial number list and adds a second record in the new table that correlates the numeric value with the alphanumeric value.  If this is not atomic then the scheme breaks down.  Removals have to be handled atomically also.

Comment: Can you explain your second paragraph, possibly with an example?  Thanks